# Mongodb, mongoid Rails 3.1.* error with Active record

Tags: activerecord, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid

After 3-4 months when I returned to another project on RoR, with Mongoid. I was stuck on the strange issue. As I had been following Mongoid documented.
so generated `mongoid.yml`, deleted `database.yml`. and changed

```
#require 'rails/all'
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie" # Uncomment this line for Rails 3.1+
```

in `config/application.rb`.

I am still facing the issue. with, starting the server.

```
configuration.rb:85:in `method_missing': undefined method `active_record' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x9441fd4> (NoMethodError)
```

Oops I had to comment out
`config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict`
and
`config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5`
in `config/environments/development.rb`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Comment the following lines

```
config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
```

in config/environments/development.rb and config/environments/test.rb